# I want to print before and after values of dictionary but the output is not correct?

Tags: python, dictionary

```
person= {
    "name": "jitty"
}

temp = person.values()
person["name"] = "shippy"
print(temp)  #before change
print(person.values()) #After change
```

Expected output:

```
dict_values(['jitty'])
dict_values(['shippy'])
```

Output:

```
dict_values(['shippy'])
dict_values(['shippy'])
```

Comment: Please format your code properly. `.values()` is a view backed by the original. It's not a copy

Comment: you may try temp=person.copy().values()

Answer (score 0):

You're printing both outputs after changing.
You can try this instead

```
person= {

"name": "jitty" }

temp = person.values() 
print(temp) #before change 
person["name"] = "shippy" 

print(person.values()) #After change
```

Output :

```
dict_values(['jitty']) 
dict_values(['shippy'])
```